# save-whole-line

Tags: org-mode, copy-paste, kill-ring

`kill-whole-line` works as I want. It cuts the line, and when I'm in `org-mode` it cuts the whole collapsed subtree.

What I need is just that as copy instead of cut. There is a multitude of suggestions here how to copy a whole line, which all work, but in `org-mode` they simply do not copy the whole collapsed subtree, they just copy the first line.

Comment: FWIW, a common Emacs idiom for emulating `save-*` commands is performing the corresponding kill command and then immediately undoing/yanking the kill, e.g. `C-k` followed by `C-y`, as the former kill modifies the `kill-ring` whereas the latter undo or yank does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How 'bout

```
(defun save-whole-line ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (forward-visible-line 0)
    (let ((start (point)))
      (forward-visible-line 1)
      (kill-new (buffer-substring start (point))))))
```

The `(forward-visible-line 0)` was taken from `kill-whole-line`'s source code, and the `kill-new` was taken from `copy-region-as-kill`'s source code (both of which should be easy to find via `C-h f <function-name> RET`).

Comment: Thanks for that code. It works as expected. I don't get it. If kill-whole-line is a part of emacs why not save-whole-line?

Comment: Better would be a general "kill prefix" which you could use before any navigation command.

Comment: How about making a suggestion on the emacs mailing list? I think you have a point here.

Answer (score 2):

To copy an entire subtree (including the parts that are hidden) use `C-c C-x M-w` which runs `org-copy-special`

To copy an entire subtree (NOT including the parts that are hidden) you can mark the entire section and run `C-c C-x v` which runs `org-copy-visible`

(these work for Spacemacs 0.200.9@27.0.50 but I believe they also work for regular emacs)

Comment: No, what I need is an mode-universal command like kill-whole-line. org-copy-special works quite differently than kill-whole-line. Combining org-copy-special with org-copy-visible works somehow but it is far from the universal behaviour of kill-whole-line